# Eclipse permissions for created files and folders windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows, permissions

When I create a new file/folder in Eclipse it creates it with very restricted permissions... After I create file/folder I need to go into Windows Explorer

Right Click -> Properties -> Security tab -> Edit -> Full permissions for my user

Before I can do anything to the file. Is there any way to set defaults... What is the equivalent of umask in Windows?? God I hate this operating system

Comment: Where are you creating them? Do you own the workspace directory?

Comment: Yes... It's on the local hard drive of a desktop comp, it's a folder i created as a regular user

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are an admin ,try right clicking and opening eclipse as admin

Comment: That's not really a viable solution.... I don't want to have to remember to run as admin every time i start eclipse